# Is there a way to load AMD modules from modules compiled with Webpack (at runtime over the network)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, amd, webpack-2

Is there a way to load AMD modules from modules compiled with Webpack (at runtime over the network)?

f.e., I have

```
import Blah from './Blah'
import AmdModule from './AmdModule'
```

where `AmdModule` is an AMD module that has a single `define()` call in it. I don't want webpack to compile that file and I don't want webpack to include it in the bundle. Maybe that file doesn't even exist at compile time, but will exist on the asset server. I want that file to be loaded at runtime, over the network.

Is there some way to make Webpack do that kind of stuff? I was thinking maybe to import that file with RequireJS, but then it breaks Webpack modules because there's no way to wait for the module to load and then export something asynchronously in webpack modules.

Ideally, I'd like for webpack to wait for those files to be loaded from the network before executing the module that needs it.

Is something like this possible?

As requirement, the to-be-loaded-by-network file can not be compiled, it must remain an AMD define() module loaded over the network, untouched, no source map needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack can specify different methods ( AMD and CommonJs ) to load code **on demand**.

Here is an extract from [the webpack guide](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) :

> To clarify a common misunderstanding: Code Splitting is not just about
>   extracting common code into a shared chunk. The more notable feature
>   is that Code Splitting can be used to split code into an on demand
>   loaded chunk.

Regarding how you can configure how externals are exposed you can look at this sample ( [webpack/examples/externals](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/externals) ) :

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    externals: [
        "add",
        {
            "subtract": {
                root: "subtract",
                commonjs2: "./subtract",
                commonjs: ["./math", "subtract"],
                amd: "subtract"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In my case, I used the `amd` libraryTarget, which outputs a `define()` module with the webpack bundle inside of it. Then we can pass external dependencies to the webpack bundle with RequireJS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, just add to externals:

```
module.exports = {
   ... (all config stuff),
   output: {
     filename: "[name].js",
     path: path,
     libraryTarget: 'amd'
   },
   externals : [
      'module the AmdModule is requiring'
  ]
}
```

I'm using it to pack my module/plugin to be load in a framework and the modules uses some modules from the target framework, so webpack should not include the modules. Externals does avoid include the framework modules inside my plugin module and still waiting for those modules to load on run time.

Externals are exactly for it:

> **Applications and externals**
>
> You can also use the externals option to import an existing API into applications. For example, if you want to use jQuery from a CDN via a separate  tag while still explicitly declaring it as a dependency via require("jquery"), you would specify it as external like so: { externals: { jquery: "jQuery" } }.

@NicoD: External Indicates dependencies that should not be bundled by webPack but instead remain requested by the resulting bundle. To get the module you have to use a loader as [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/)

Comment: are you sure `externals` doesn't just pull the result from a global variable on `window`? If you read my OP, I want Webpack to load `AmdModule` from a network location, not grab it off `window` as in `window.AmdModule`. Does it do that?

Comment: If the module is on the server, and you don't want webpack to include it on the bundle but still wait it to load, it does work, I'm changing my answer a bit to add more context

Comment: @trusktr External Indicates dependencies that should not be bundled by webPack but instead remain requested by the resulting bundle. To get the module you have to use a loader as  [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/)

Comment: Hey @NicoD thank you for share about script.js it sounds really handy

Comment: @Louis can you paste the first line of the code webpack generates? It should be: define(["modules on externals"],  function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_1__,... I'm really not seen how it wouldn't work

Comment: @Drix Yes, it does, so my objection does not hold. The documentation shows only one type of output.  So using `external` to load an AMD module will work only if `libraryTarget` is `amd` or `umd` (yes, I checked `umd`). I would point this out in the answer because that's a Webpack constraint due to how it works, not a general constraint on AMD. (I've written quite a few scripts that were not AMD  modules and yet used RequireJS to load AMD modules.)

Comment: @Louis However some people use requirejs and webpack when migrating legacy code : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1046

Comment: @NicoD I know. I'm among those people.

Comment: I can't get `libraryTarget` with `externals` to work. I have code does `import blah from 'jquery'`, the external is listed as `jquery: 'jQuery'`, and the top of the compiled bundle looks like this: `define(function() { return /******/ (function(modules) {`. I don't see any mention of `jQuery` there, or how it can possibly ever load `jQuery`. Can you show output of an example that shows webpack will use define() to load an AMD `define()` module in order to give it as a dependency to webpack's inner modules?

Comment: Oh, nvm! For some reason my editor cached the old file. I see: `define(["jQuery"], function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_67__) { return /******/`, so I can get jQuery from requirejs!! Woo!!