# How can I import an object from a webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, node-modules, module-export

I'm trying to create a node package to make form validation much easier for front-end developers.
All the logic behind the form validation is on this [validate.ts](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/src/validate.ts) file.
I also worked to fully integrate these validation methods with some data types (Number, String, and Arrays) and HTMLInputElements, you can check that on the [validateIntegration.ts](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/src/validateIntegration.ts) file.

As you can see I'm exporting an instance of the FormValidation class on the validate.ts (L312) file, and I'm importing it on the validateIntegration.ts (L1) file, at the end using webpack I create a single bundle js file with both the form validation class and the integration with the data types and the input elements.

**The problem Is that I'm unable to import the `fvalidation` instance exported in the validate.ts (L312) file from the resulting [fvalidation.js](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/fvalidation.js) bundle**

When I import the file in the following way:

```
import '../fvalidation.js'
```

The integration of the form validation works perfectly fine, you can check that in the [tests/validation.mjs](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/pull/4/commits/c96228a7b38fb4a577020ac9dcb57908d51ad92d#diff-de660f63cde3d67b85a67e2a4d1ceb512aa0dab3c49b032862de0fcd26555bf4) file.

But, when I try to import the instance of the form validation class to use its additional methods or to change some validation properties I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: fvalidation
```

You can check that in the [tests/validate.mjs](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/pull/4/commits/c96228a7b38fb4a577020ac9dcb57908d51ad92d#diff-4b9d0af876e26960074719c98bb2171a3c3589caeb8923793bf23e206af6c1ae) file.

It's important to note that I've already added the library and the libraryTarget in the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/webpack.config.js#L24) file

NOTE: Btw I would love to receive feedback about the code, if you think there's something that I should improve or if you have any ideas that you would like to share, feel free to open an issue.

---

### EDIT

I keep getting suggestions from an article that treats how to **`import`** an AMD module into ES6, but the thing is that because what I'm trying to build is a node package that will be installed and imported I don't want any programmer to write any additional code to import the `fvalidation` instance; so I shouldn't make any changes on the `import` side if that makes sense, there's something that I should change on my code that will allow the programmer to simply write:

```
import { fvalidation } from '../fvalidation.js'
```

and be able to use all the validation methods from that instance without any additional configuration, but I don't know what I need to change since on the ts files I'm already using ES modules, and also on my tsconfig file I have the target set to ES6

Comment: What does `fvalidation` export?

Comment: `fvalidation` is an instance of the `FormValidation` class, exported from the [validate.ts](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/src/validate.ts) file

Comment: Try using the named import `import { fvalidation } from '../fvalidation.js'`?

Comment: That's what I did and I got the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: fvalidation` you can check that on the [tests/validate.mjs](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/pull/4/commits/c96228a7b38fb4a577020ac9dcb57908d51ad92d#diff-4b9d0af876e26960074719c98bb2171a3c3589caeb8923793bf23e206af6c1ae) file

Comment: What about using CJS? `const fvalidation = require('../fvalidation.js')`?

Comment: Well, I want it to work with ES6 imports, but even if I try to use CJS I get the following error: `require is not defined` since CJS can't be used in a browser context. More details about require is not defined: [https://codedamn.com/news/javascript/fix-require-is-not-defined](https://codedamn.com/news/javascript/fix-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: The code hasn't been written for ESM. Without rewriting the module to work with ESM you can use a bundler to combine them, which does understand `require`

Comment: What do you mean the code hasn't been written for ESM? what do I need to change in order for it to work with ES modules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import existing AMD module into ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805234/import-existing-amd-module-into-es6-module)

Comment: The module has been written for AMD modules. You will likely need to use a bundler like webpack, gulp, grunt, rollup, etc to use.

Comment: But I'm already using webpack, in fact, the file from which I'm trying to import fvalidation is the resulting bundle from webpack. you can check that file here [fvalidation.js](https://github.com/jorgeabrahan/fvalidation/blob/main/fvalidation.js)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860191/is-there-a-way-to-load-amd-modules-from-modules-compiled-with-webpack-at-runtim

Comment: Changing the library target to `amd` on the webpack configuration file as suggested in the linked article didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was exporting the instance using ES modules on the typescript files after webpack creates the bundle the exports were changed to the CJS syntax, to prevent this I changed my webpack configuration file as shown:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/validateIntegration.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: './',
    filename: 'fvalidation.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    library: {
      type: 'module'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import a variable from webpack using the plugins - Define Plugin

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const myvariable = {whatever: true}

const config = {
...,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'myvariable': JSON.stringify({hello: 'world'})
   })
```

**myfile.js**

```js
console.log('myvariable = ', myvariable);
```